# adding checkbox to meta

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have a custom post type that is working well and displaying/saving all the text fields. The issue is now I need to add 4 check boxes but not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

```
function fitter_info() {
        global $post;

        //Fitter Meta
                // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="fittermeta_noncename" id="fittermeta_noncename" value="' . 
                wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

                // Get the fitter data if its already been entered
                $phone = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_phone', true);


                // Echo out the fields
                echo '<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="_phone" value="' . $phone  . '" class="widefat" style="width:40%; margin:5px 20px;" />';


                echo '<br><br>';

                //The Checkboxes
                echo '<label> JR. Fitter </label><input style="margin:0 10px;" type="checkbox" name="fittermeta"id="meta-checkbox" value="jr" />';
                echo '<label> Full Fitter </label><input style="margin:0 10px;" type="checkbox" name="fittermeta" id="meta-checkbox" value="full"/>';
                echo '<label> Master Fitter </label><input style="margin:0 10px;" type="checkbox" name="fittermeta" id="meta-checkbox" value="master"/>';
                echo '<label> Award Winning Fitter </label><input style="margin:0 10px;" type="checkbox" name="fittermeta" id="meta-checkbox" value="award"/>';

    }

    // Save the Metabox Data

    function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {

        // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
        // because save_post can be triggered at other times
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['fittermeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
        }

        // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
            return $post->ID;

        // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
        // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

        $fitters_meta['_phone'] = $_POST['_phone'];

        // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

        foreach ($fitters_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
            if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
            $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
                update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
                add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            }
            if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
        }

    }

    add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to the parts that the question really is about? This would allow people to take it and put it into local test setups and help you much easier. Thanks.

Comment: I took out some of the extra. Most of that code is showing how I set up my meta fields and save them since that is part of adding and saving a checkbox.